# cryptography python encryption for creating password error

Tags: python

I have a problem in printing the encryption in file for password using cryptography, I want to encrypt the creation of master key and the login key to decrypt and check password

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

class hash_password():
    def genewrite_key():
        key= Fernet.generate_key()
        with open("pass.key","wb") as key_file:
            key_file.write(key)

    def get_key():
        key= open("pass.key","rb").read()
        return key


class signIn():
    def create_masterkey(hash):
        hash_password.genewrite_key()
        cr_pass = input("Create your password so you can access your data in future and please remember it: ")
        hash = cr_pass.encode()
        key= hash_password.get_key()
        a= Fernet(key)
        txt = a.encrypt(hash)

        with open('P1ssW0rd.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(hash) +"\n")     
        if len(cr_pass)<= 6:
            print("Password is too short")
            signIn().create_masterkey()
        else: print("Passcode Created Successfully!")

    def Login():
        
        hash_password.genewrite_key() 
        key= hash_password.get_key()
        a= Fernet(key)
        login_pass = input("whats you passcode? ")
        file = open("P1ssW0rd.txt")
        decoded_text = a.decrypt(hash)

        if(login_pass in file.read()):
            print("true password")
        else:
            print("Creditionals doesn't exist")
            signIn().create_masterkey()
        file.close()
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: its not encrypting the password or writing in  password.txt file when running it , i dont know where is the mistake ?

Comment: What is `hash_password`? If this code runs then it must be a nonlocal class-instance, or a module for which the `import` statement has been omitted from the code you present.  Either way you haven't  shown us how it is defined and without that we can't run your code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add full code